# Replace text in an Android TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm updating text for my android app every 5 seconds but the previous text is not removed by the new text. The new text is just placed below the previous text. How can I have the new text replace the old text?

```java
TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myText = myText + "\nYour car model is: " a.getcarType();
myText = myText + "\nYour car year is: " a.getcaryear();
...

myTextView.append(myText);
```

Comment: Did the answers work for you?

Comment: yah thanks for the negataive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the text instead of appending to it:

```
TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myText = myText + "\nYour car model is: " a.getcarType();
myText = myText + "\nYour car year is: " a.getcaryear();
...

myTextView.setText(myText);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `myTextView.setText(myText);` . Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
myTextView.append(myText);
```

You can use

```
myTextView.setText(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `myTextView.append(myText)` you are saying "get the text in `myTextView` and add `myText` to it"

so you should use `myTextView.setText(myText)` which will clear the TextView before updating it.

```
TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myText = myText + "\nYour car model is: " a.getcarType();
myText = myText + "\nYour car year is: " a.getcaryear();
...

myTextView.setText(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText("your string here");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TextView myTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myText = myText + "\nYour car model is: " a.getcarType();
myText = myText + "\nYour car year is: " a.getcaryear();
...

//myTextView.append(myText); 
myTextView.setText(myText);
```